# Android JWPlayer fullscreen on Orientation Changed And Retain Video

Tags: android, orientation, fullscreen, jwplayer

I am using JWPlayer So Try to Retain Video And FullScreen On Orietation Changed

my code is :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(UIH.TAG_SCR, "Is Rotated : " + isRotated);
    if(!isRotated) {
        playerView.stop();
    } else {
        isRotated = false;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.i(UIH.TAG_SCR, "ORIENTATION : " + newConfig.orientation);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        isRotated = true;
        Log.i(UIH.TAG_SCR, "ORIENTATION : PORTRAIT");
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        isRotated = true;
        Log.i(UIH.TAG_SCR, "ORIENTATION : LANDSCAPE");
        playerView.setFullscreen(true, true);
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

But it doesn't works!

LogCat is :

> I/SCREEN_TAG: ORIENTATION : 1
>
> I/SCREEN_TAG: ORIENTATION : PORTRAIT
>
> I/SCREEN_TAG: Is Rotated : true
>
> I/SCREEN_TAG: ORIENTATION : 2
>
> I/SCREEN_TAG: ORIENTATION : LANDSCAPE
>
> I/SCREEN_TAG: Is Rotated : true

Comment: any one can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        if(playerView.getFullscreen()) {
            playerView.setFullscreen(false, true);
        }
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        if(!playerView.getFullscreen()) {
            playerView.setFullscreen(true, true);
        }
    }
}
```

It works to me.

Comment: It Works Well, Thank you